# Pivoting table only returns 1 row

Tags: mysql, pivot, dynamic-sql

My SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/729a9/1

As you can see, despite there being two rows in the table, there is one row returned.

It's also the highest id, so maybe that has something to do with it?

I'm stumped like a log, sorry to say.

SQL:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(distinct
             CONCAT(
              'max(case when `pat`.`name` = ''',
               `pat`.name,
               ''' then `pa`.`value` end) as `',
               `pat`.name, '`'
              )
            ) INTO @list 
FROM `product_attribute_types` pat;

SET @sql = CONCAT('select ', @list, ' 
                  from `products`  `p` 
                  LEFT JOIN `product_attributes` `pa` 
                    ON `p`.id=`pa`.`product_id`
                  LEFT JOIN `product_attribute_types` `pat`
                        ON `pa`.`type`=`pat`.`id`
                  ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: I must say that it unfair that you deleted your previous question which was answered only to repost a new version of the question with a change.  If your requirements change then you should either comment to the author of the answers or post a new question. Deleting and reposting is very rude -  10k only users -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775409/selecting-dynamic-column-names-from-multiple-tables

Comment: Is the `products` table correct in your fiddle? You have both blue pants and green shirt for the same product ID.

Comment: You should probably make `product_id, type` a unique key in `product_attributes`, to prevent this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: you have had two attributes for the same product_id = 1, change table `product_attributes` in this way -

```
INSERT INTO `product_attributes` (`product_id`,`type`,`value`) VALUES
  (1,1,'blue'),
  (1,2,'shirt'),
  (2,1,'green'),
  (2,2,'pants');
```

Then try this one -

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(pat.name = ''', name, ''', pa.value, NULL)) AS ', name
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM product_attribute_types;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT pa.product_id, ', @sql, ' FROM product_attributes pa INNER JOIN product_attribute_types pat ON pa.type = pat.id GROUP BY pa.product_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Result:

```
+------------+-------+-------+
| product_id | color | name  |
+------------+-------+-------+
|          1 | blue  | shirt |
|          2 | green | pants |
+------------+-------+-------+
```

Add WHERE filter if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a GROUP BY clause in `@sql`, as well as the product ID that the row refers to.

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('select p.id, ', @list, ' 
                  from `products`  `p` 
                  LEFT JOIN `product_attributes` `pa` 
                    ON `p`.id=`pa`.`product_id`
                  LEFT JOIN `product_attribute_types` `pat`
                        ON `pa`.`type`=`pat`.`id`
                  GROUP BY p.id
                  ');
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55183/8)

Comment: Still doesn't work, they want to display both colors green and blue under the color -- etc for the other column -- your returns null -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/729a9/27 -- Fiddle is showing a hard-coded version of the same query.

Comment: i don't understand, you're asking for the MAX of each attribute, which means you'll always have only 1 row returned.

Comment: @bluefeet See my comment above -- I think he has the wrong data in his `products` table.

Comment: @Barmar They probably do, they had wrong data when I previously answered this question as well.  They need something distinct that will give a row number over each product id.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to change rows 3 and 4 of `product_attributes` to have `product_id = 2`. Now the results are reasonable.

Comment: @Barmar I'm actually not sure if that solves it.  If they have a product that has multiple colors - shirt then the product id would be the same.

Comment: @bluefeet The whole idea of pivoting assumes that there's a unique key that you can group on to get the rows of the resulting table. If a shirt comes in different colors, you have to give them different product IDs.

Comment: @Barmar Trust me I understand the concept of pivoting.  They don't need different product numbers, they need to have something that makes the row unique.  In SQL Server it would be a row number that is partitioned by the product ID

Comment: That's funny, taking into consideration the following [Top](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pivot/topusers) :-).