# Complex MySQL query from 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

So far I haven't been successful in my search on combining 4 tables. I have 4 tables:

**content**

```
content_id | source_id | content_title   | content_date
--------------------------------------------------------
1          | 1         | The factory     | 189982398300
2          | 2         | Cold and cloudy | 189982398299
3          | 2         | Green tea       | 189982398298
```

**sources**

```
source_id | source_name
-------------------
1         | BBC
2         | Reuters
```

**settings**

```
setting_id | setting_name
-------------------------------
1          | bbc_iplayer_string
2          | reuters_video_id
3          | reuters_category
```

**content_join_settings**

```
content_id | setting_id | setting_data
------------------------------------------
1          | 1          | Js88sdhjsd0gDS09
2          | 2          | video_8AJK3ADJD8
2          | 3          | weather
3          | 2          | video_K7KD8N2ND9
3          | 3          | food and drinks
```

So as you might have already noticed every content record has it's own source linked to it, and comes with extra settings depending on the source. BBC posts have an `bbc_iplayer_string`, and posts from Reuters have a `reuters_video_id` and a `reuters_category`. Of course this is just an example.

I'd like to have the results combined, and with the `setting_name` as a column name. I'm not sure how to explain it so I'll show it:

```
content_id | source_name | content_title   | content_date | bbc_iplayer_string | reuters_video_id | reuters_category
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          | BBC         | The factory     | 189982398300 | Js88sdhjsd0gDS09   | NULL             | NULL
2          | Reuters     | Cold and cloudy | 189982398299 | NULL               | video_8AJK3ADJD8 | weather
3          | Reuters     | Green tea       | 189982398298 | NULL               | video_K7KD8N2ND9 | food and drinks
```

I'm not very skilled in complex MySQL queries. I don't know where to start looking, let alone what to search for. I started with this query but I have no idea how to continue. I'm probably not even close.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  content,
  sources,
  settings,
  content_join_settings
WHERE
  content.content_id = content_join_settings.content_id AND
  settings.setting_id = content_join_settings.setting_id AND
  sources.source_id = content.source_id
GROUP BY
  content.content_id
ORDER BY
  content.content_date
  DESC
```

Comment: have you tried inner join yet ?

Comment: Why the group by?   Most databases will throw an error for this on the group by clause...MySQL doesn't return an error and does the wrong thing instead.  Group by's are for aggregates and generally don't apply to a select *.   You're also using the old join syntax...are you opposed to using inner join tablea a on...syntax instead?

Comment: @raiyan - he is doing an inner join, just old syntax.

Comment: do you have just three settings? or there could be more?

Comment: - Raiyan: I don't have much experience with it.
- Twelfth: To be honest the GROUP_BY brought me a step closer to cleaner results. I'm open to suggestions.
- fthiella: there could be many more settings to every source

Comment: @bob you are looking to 'pivot' out the data...try searching for a pivot answer (I can get to it tonight if you still need).  Group by will clean results for MySQL, but it's really just grouping information together incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction Twelfth! I will look into it right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join the tables, and then pivot the results to move rows into columns.

```
SELECT c.content_id, s.source_name, c.content_title, c.content_date,
       MAX(CASE setting_name WHEN 'bbc_iplayer_string' THEN setting_data END) AS bbc_iplayer_string,
       MAX(CASE setting_name WHEN 'reuters_video_id' THEN setting_data END) AS reuters_video_id,
       MAX(CASE setting_name WHEN 'reuters_category' THEN setting_data END) AS reuters_category
FROM content AS c
INNER JOIN sources AS s ON s.source_id = c.source_id
INNER JOIN content_join_settings AS cjs ON cjs.content_id = c.content_id
INNER JOIN settings as st ON st.setting_id = cjs.setting_id
GROUP BY c.content_id
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8ca42/2)

Comment: I almost don't dare to ask since you helped me out so much already, but I have a follow-up question: is it possible to get the `setting_name`s dynamically? I'm using a lot of different sources that all have their own settings, it would be a very long query on the long run.

Comment: You need to write dynamic SQL for that. I'll see if I can find an answer that shows it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780382/pivoting-table-only-returns-1-row/19784339#19784339

Answer (score -2):

Would this help ?

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  content as ct inner join sources as ss on ct.source_id = ss.source_id
  inner join content_join_settings as cst on ct.setting_id = cst.setting_id
  inner join settings as st on st.setting_id = cst.setting_id
GROUP BY
  content.content_id
ORDER BY
  content.content_date
  DESC
```

Comment: Congratulations, you've successfully changed his syntax from the old to the new, but didn't come close to addressing the question

Comment: wow, a -1 even before the page loads since i submit. care to explain why ?

Comment: explain is above...there is no issue with his syntax, the join in the where clause is an older way of looking at it, but still functional.  his question was "I'd like to have the results combined, and with the setting_name as a column name", please explain how you answered that.

Comment: ok, got it. first i thought he needs a col whose name will be 'setting_name'. took me a while to realize the question was quite different than what I thought.